# Can I observe the camera transform of a SCNView?

Tags: ios, scenekit

I have a `SCNView` with it's `allowsCameraControl` property enabled. I would like to observe the camera orientation while it is changing (by user gestures), how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `allowsCameraControl` to true, `SceneKit` adds a Camera as a child of the rootNode.

As such to access information from the camera you can do something like this in the following `delegate` callback:

```
 func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {

    //1. Get The Camera From The ARSCNScene
    if let currentPointOfView = augmentedRealityView?.pointOfView{

        let pitch = currentPointOfView.eulerAngles.x
        let yaw =   currentPointOfView.eulerAngles.y
        let roll =  currentPointOfView.eulerAngles.z

        print("""
            Pitch = \(degreesFrom(pitch))
            Yaw = \(degreesFrom(yaw))
            Roll = \(degreesFrom(roll))
            """)

    }
}

/// Convert Radians To Degrees
///
/// - Parameter radian: Float
/// - Returns: Float
func degreesFrom( _ radian: Float) -> Float{

   return radian * Float(180.0 / Double.pi)

}
```

Whereby Pitch, Yaw & Roll refer to the following:
[image]

Hope this gets you started...

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. I knew about the pointOfView SCNNode, with camera attached. I couldn't figure out how to get notified of changes to it, but your reference to the SCNSceneRendererDelegate got me on the right track.